# discord.js say command repeating message in multiple lines

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I am working on my bot, and for my `;say` command I have the following code. The issue is, that when a user does something like ";say hi" it repeats as ;say on one line, goes down a line, and on that line it says hi. Before I added in a command handler, the command worked fine, however only now am I running into issues.

The code (including vars + command handler portion) -

```js
const Prefix = require('./../../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: "say",
    description: "Says the user input",
    execute (Client, message, Args) {
        let Say = message.content.substring(({Prefix} + 'say').Args).split(" ");
        let Output = Say.splice(1);
        message.channel.send(Output);
        message.delete({ timeout: 1 });
    },
};
```

in case it comes of necessity for some reason, my config.json file (might be an issue with the prefix) is in the "container" directory in the below file location -

`container/commands/fun/say.js`

Answer (score 0):

At first, why don't you use `` message.content.substring(`${Prefix}say`); `` instead of these two lines

```
    let Say = message.content.substring(({Prefix} + 'say').Args).split(" ");
    let Output = Say.splice(1);
```

that would be the same, no?
I also think if you have a problem like this it's probably because there's something missing in the event handling part of your code.

Also you need to select the prefix from your config.json file, by adding `.prefix` or the name of your variable in your .json file after the `require('./../../config.json');` not to get the entire object.

Comment: I wasn't too sure what you meant in that last part, however I just had to switch it to `message.content.split('; say ').join('")` for it to work apparently. Thanks for the help, I tried what you said and it did make the problem a little better!